# Runtime customizable asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, runtime, customization

I'm currently working on an asp.net application which roughly speaking makes 'CRUD' operations on entities stored in a database.

I would like to make this application customizable by the users themselves: some users (e.g. with some 'admin' roles) 
should be able to add some fields to the default applications entities or even link some new custom entities to the existing one.

I want this customisation to be possible form the application itself, that is at runtime. There would be a dedicated page to define new fields 
and new tables. It would also be nice to have the possibility to design how to display these custom data (a form or grid...)

Has anybody some experience on that? Does any framework exist?

Is it better to store all information concerning the customization in the application database and interpret that information each time the application is restarted? Or is it better to dynamically generate new tables/fields in the database and
generate/compile code (asp, C#)?

That kind of customization exist in 'Sharepoint' or 'Salesforce'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XSLT to generate HTML pages dynamically from XML` data defined on admin page.

Create an admin page which lets you create new fields. Store the information on that page in 
an XML document and save it in your database.

While rendering your grid or page with custom fields , transform your XML into and HTML using XSLT.

See these links for more information -

http://aspalliance.com/1296_Transform_XML_into_HTML_Using_XSLT.2
http://www.webdevelopersjournal.com/articles/xml_to_html.html